# JavaScript - Get corresponding request for Promise.all response

Tags: javascript, promise

I am creating an array of Promises to fire off all at once, like so:

```
let categories = ["cat1", "cat3", "cat3"];
let categoryRequests = []; // array of promises
categories.forEach(category => {
    categoryRequests.push(getCategoryResult({category})); // getCategoryResult returns a promise
});
```

Once all the promises are resolved, I get an array of responses, like so:

```
let categoryResponses = await Promise.all(categoryRequests);
categoryResponses.forEach(categoryResponse => {
    categoryResponse.categoryType = "???"; // should be a value from categories array
});
```

I want to add a "categoryType" field to each response, corresponding to the category that was used in the initial request. From my understanding, the array of responses is NOT in the same order as the array of Promises.

One way I can think of is to execute each promise in serial, append the corresponding category to the response, and fire off the next promise. However, I would like to fire off the promises in parallel.

Is there a way to map the initial request to the array of responses?

Comment: If the order did indeed get lost, one solution is to create a custom Promise that resolves to `{ id: 1, result: x }` (where x is, say, the result of a `fetch()`), then sort the result array based on `id`. It should also be pointed out that the first snippet can be rewritten to `let categoryRequests = categories.map(category => getCategoryResult({category}));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is preserved, otherwise it would not be possible to correlate resolved promises to requests.

See the [Promise.all() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

> Returned values will be in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order.